# Wordpress how to use post image to dynamically set the url background in css

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, thumbnails, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to dynamically add background inside CSS using php, using the Wordpress post image.

```
background: <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ 
                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'destacados');
                echo 'url(".$img['0'].") no-repeat center'  } ?>;
```

Comment: People seriously need to stop doing downvotes just because they feel the question is too trivial or the problem with the question is so easy to solve they ought to get a downvote. Everyone has had a situation like that, and I'm pretty sure you wouldn't want to get the same result from the peer around.

Comment: @Yisera, I didn't downvote, but I did vote to close this question as it is just a typographical error. These questions aren't a good fit for SO since they provide little to no help for future visitors of the site and are easily resolved using basic troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: @DrydenLong, I believe someone can have exactly the same problem, and double check if it is a typographical error, or use it as an example. I know it was a newbie question. However I got to the point, and I think it was complete enough to be easily answered. Anyway, I somewhat understand your attitude.

Comment: @autorun The problem is that you can't search for typos since you don't even know that a typo is the problem. This post would never be found by someone with the same issue since they have no idea what they are looking for. Your question was to the point and easily understandable though, which is why I didn't downvote it. It is, however, one of many posts on the site that revolve around typos. If those posts were of any value, you would have seen one of them, realized your mistake and never posted this question. Either way, I'm glad you got it resolved, good luck!

Comment: Ok, but hey, the title is "Setting dynamic url background" and wordpress/php/css tags, someone could stumble upon it... anyway, sorry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background: <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ 
                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'destacados');
                echo "url('".$img['0']."') no-repeat center";
             } ?>;
```

the quotes were wrong and a semicolon was missing.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, I had got confused with " '